# How to send multiple files in postman ReSTful web service?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, file-upload, postman

I am using ReSTful webservice. I am uploading multiple photos with one function (PHP).

I have used `$num_files = count($_FILES['myfile']['name'])` to count number of files that are to be uploaded but this always gives 1:

[image]

When I print `$_FILES['myfile']['name']` or `$_FILES` it returns last image.

Am I suppose to do any setting to send multiple files at a time?

```
<?php
if($result=="success")
{
    $num_files = count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    Zend_Debug::dump($num_files);
    die;
    for( $i=0; $i < $num_files; $i++ )
    {
        $name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
        $temp_path = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $image_name = Helper_common::getUniqueNameForFile( $name );

        echo $image_name;
        die;
        // Set the upload folder path
        $target_path = $originalDirecory."/";


        // Set upload image path
        $image_upload_path = $target_path.$image_name;
        move_uploaded_file($temp_path, $image_upload_path);

        //if(move_uploaded_file($temp_path, $image_upload_path))
        //{
        // Set 800*800 popup thumbnail...
        // Set popup directory...
        $thumbnail_directory=$popUpDirectory."/";
        // Set thumbnail name...
        $thumb_name1=$thumbnail_directory.'thumbnail_'.$image_name;
        // Set width and height of the thumbnail...
        $thumb_width=800;
        $thumb_height=800;
        $thumb1=Helper_common::generateThumbnail($image_upload_path, $thumb_name1, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);

        //if($thumb)
        //{
            // Set 435*333 thumbnail...
            // Set thumbnail directory...
            $thumbnail_directory=$wallDirecory."/";
            // Set thumbnail name...
            $thumb_name2=$thumbnail_directory.'thumbnail_'.$image_name;
            // Set width and height of the thumbnail...
            $thumb_width=435;
            $thumb_height=435;
            $thumb2=Helper_common::generateThumbnail($image_upload_path, $thumb_name2, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);

            //if($thumb)
            //{
                // Set 176*176 thumbnail...
                // Set thumbnail directory...
                $thumbnail_directory=$galleryDirectory."/";
                // Set thumbnail name...
                $thumb_name3=$thumbnail_directory.'thumbnail_'.$image_name;
                // Set width and height of the thumbnail...
                $thumb_width=176;
                $thumb_height=176;
                $thumb_smart_resize_3 = Helper_ImageResizer::smart_resize_image($image_upload_path, NULL, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, false, $thumb_name3, false);
                $thumb3=Helper_common::generateThumbnail($image_upload_path, $thumb_name3, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            //if($thumb)
            //{
                $profile_thumb=$thumb3;
                // Set 131*131 thumbnail...
                // Set thumbnail directory....
                $thumbnail_directory = $thumbnailsDirectory."/";
                // Set thumbnail name....
                $thumb_name4 = $thumbnail_directory.'thumbnail_'.$image_name;
                $thumb_width=131;
                $thumb_height=131;
                $thumb_smart_resize_4=Helper_ImageResizer::smart_resize_image($image_upload_path, NULL, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, false, $thumb_name4, false);
                $thumb4=Helper_common::generateThumbnail($image_upload_path, $thumb_name4, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);

                }
```

Comment: The curly brackets are incomplete can you please post the full code for the section

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I got a solution.
I need to make myfile an array like this:
myfile[] :)

Comment: any array of data you have to mention it with [ ] , in your case you have to send multiple files via array [ ] as in in postman you have to mention it in key parameter myfile[ ]

Comment: I guess it's not needed anymore or added automatically. At least it works without it in my case.

Answer (score 89):

You need to add a ***square bracket*** **[]** sign to the parameter. Look at the following image. I add **file[]** to upload multiple images from the postman.

[image]

Answer (score 36):

You can simple add multiple lines with same key and postman converts them to array. No need to add [] as suffix to key.

**Request**

[image]

**Response**

[image]

If you have an array **objects** that need to passed then follow below pattern

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `[]` is just and artifact from PHP that is not standard in all languages

Answer (score 13):

**Update 2020 Postman**

You don't need to add `[ ]` just put the param name and select files.

Comment: works in the 2021 version

Comment: You don't, but you'll get only one file on the backend. First one, probably.

Comment: mmm no, you get all of them

Answer (score 6):

I am using Postman v9.21.0

Steps:

1. Create a new Post request in Postman. Like https://localhost:44394/api/BlobStorage/UploadFiles
2. Click on Body and then select **form-data**
3. Type the key name like "files" in the KEY column
4. Here is the tricky part. Hover the mouse on entered key **files**. You will see **Text** on the right corner. Change it to **File**. Now you will see Select Files in the VALUE column.
5. Click Select Files to select the files you want to upload.
6. Click **Send** after selecting the files.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yeah,last version of postman made a bad update.

**But, you can download the chrome extensions of postman and send multiple files with it, it still works there.**

Edit: I just checked now, they brought it back, but you have to reenter the key value for files if you made them with the chromium version.

But now it works fine.

see the image

[image]