# Postman multiple image

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I'm not able to select multiple images in postman. Is their any script using which we can select multiple image? please help

[image]

Comment: Is this what your are asking for? [Multiple images in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185300/how-to-send-multiple-files-in-postman-restful-web-service)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd> when selecting items in opening dialogue:

[image]