# How can I add multiple images in Postman with POST method

Tags: postman

I want to `add multiple images` in the Postman for the `POST` API call.

Comment: This is dependent on the API you are using? Just read the docs of these APIs.

Comment: you can make files as an array[]
see more at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185300/how-to-send-multiple-files-in-postman-restful-web-service

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Following steps:

- Select **body** section in the request section
- Select **form-data**
- Add your **key** and hover on that **key** cell you will find the choice box with 2 choices(Text and File)
- Select **file** in that choice box
- Now you can find **Select Files** button in the **Value** cell (For select multiple file you can use ctrl+click)

You can see this image for a clear idea

[image]