# Postman how to send a folder to API

Tags: file-upload, postman

I'm trying to create an API endpoint that uploads an entire folder to AWS S3 and I need to test it with Postman. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185300/how-to-send-multiple-files-in-postman-restful-web-service) guides towards selecting multiple files and adding [] to show I'm working with an array. However, my goal is to upload an entire folder at the click of a button since HTML allows folder uploads using

```
  <input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory />
```

This is my current Postman screen
[image: Screenshot showing form submission using Postman]
Is it possible to select a folder, not a file, using Postman?

Comment: I don't think you can upload an entire folder on either, only files.

Comment: I'd use the AWS CLI s3 cp command for that